# How do I modify the anchor of a page URL without the page re-loading in Safari/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, anchor

I'm trying to modify the URL of a page (actually the parent frameset) in javascript like so:

```
function b(str) {
  window.top.location.hash = str // originally was "#"+str
  return true
}
```

This is being called from an anchor in gen.php, like so:

```
<a onclick="b('Page29.html')" href="Page29.html" target="content">
```

The top-level page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="320,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="menu" src="gen.php">
<frame name="content" src="about:blank">
</frameset>
</html>
```

This works fine in Firefox, but in Safari (update: AND) Chrome just changing the anchor re-loads the entire page!  This is a problem because there is state in my page that is being lost.  How can I suppress this behavior?

Here is the updated code that I am trying based on suggestion below:

```
function b(str) {
  top.location.href = "#"+str
  return true
}
```

In this case, when I click on the link, the top-level frame drops, and the page is replaced by gen.php#Page29.html.

Update: Looks like the location.hash not working in a frame is a bug in WebKit, present since 2009:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24578

Here is the fix I came up with, based on the answers below:

```
function b(str) {
    if(history.pushState) {
        top.history.replaceState(null, top.document.title, '#'+str);
    } else {
        top.location.hash = hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a looat at "pushState"
http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

Comment: pushState is not recommended since it is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: What about Android? majority of mobile devices runs on Android browser. pushState will break on these devices.

Comment: True, i did not see that android had it and the removed it again. I would use Modernizer to test for it and then provide appropriate solutions.

Comment: Its always better to use solutions that work in all browsers instead of using third party libs, and when making software for enterprise clients chances are that we need approval to use other libraries. We can check this using 1 line javascript rather than using Modernizer.

Comment: Sure you can test this with on line, and the next feature with one more line, and one more... and so on and most likely make a mistake and your checks are not reliable enough. There is a reason why so many hours of development have gone into modernizer and proper feature detection.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it is the only one that I can get to work.  Since I can detect whether or not pushState support is present in the browser, I can gracefully degrade back to setting the location hash if it is not, and since Safari and Chrome both do support it, it fixes the problem on those platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
location.href = '#newHash';
```

Or, if you mean you want to enact this on the frameset parent from within a page in an inner frame, use

```
top.location.href = '#newHash';
```

Comment: Wow, so simple I thought, I like it.  Unfortunately it isn't working for some reason, it totally breaks the frame.

Comment: You mean you want to enact this on the frameset parent and you're calling this from one of the inner frames? Try `parent.location.href` in that case.

Comment: More specifically, it changes the page URL to the URL of the frame I am setting the top-level URL from (instead of the top-level URL), plus the hash.

Comment: I'm using `window.top.document.location.href="#"+str`

Comment: @Michael for your reference, you can also mark code with BackTicks `` `like this`

Comment: `top.location.href = '#newHash';` has the same effect: the frame breaks and i am left with the URL of the frame that invoked the code, plus the new hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
function getLocationHash() {  
        alert(window.location.hash);  
    }  

function setLocationHash(hash) {  
        window.location.hash = hash;  
}
```

Call like

```
setLocationHash("#your-hash-string");
```